# Error using Imagine\Image to watermark images

Tags: php-imagine

I am trying to watermark images using the Imagine library (on a CakePHP project). Cropping images works fine - watermarking does not. I use the example from the Imagine website:

```
$imagine = new Imagine\Gd\Imagine();

$watermark = $imagine->open('/my/watermark.png');
$image     = $imagine->open('/path/to/image.jpg');
$size      = $image->getSize();
$wSize     = $watermark->getSize();

$bottomRight = new Imagine\Image\Point($size->getX() - $wSize->getX(), $size->getY() - $wSize->getY());

$image->paste($watermark, $bottomRight);
```

The original example doesn't state an instantiation procedure, so I added what I found on the page. Doing so yields the following error:

```
 Call to undefined method Imagine\Image\Box::getX()
```

How do I use it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I've used it like this and it's worked.

```
\Imagine\Image\Box::getX()
```

test it please

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
    $bottomRight = new Imagine\Image\Point($size->getX() - $wSize->getX(), $size->getY() - $wSize->getY());
```

With this:

```
    $bottomRight = new \Imagine\Image\Point($size->getWidth() - $wSize->getWidth(), $size->getHeight() - $wSize->getHeight());
```